# How can i simplify UIScreen width?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how can i simplify that code in one line?

```
CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
NSLog(@"%@",  screen.size.width);
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement will cause an exception, or should:

```
NSLog(@"%@", screen.size.width);
```

The `width` property returns a `CGFloat`. You would need to change your log statement to:

```
NSLog(@"%f", screen.size.width);
```

If you want everything on one line:

```
NSLog(@"%f", [[[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] size] width]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your really fast answer. Nice to know. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest:

```
   NSLog(@"%1.0f", [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width);
```

To get both height and width you can use [NSStringFromCGSize](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSStringFromCGSize):

```
   NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGSize([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size));
```